# Return X elements before and after sorted by a property that is not unique SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions, sql-limit

I am trying to write a query that returns X elements before and after a given entity sorted by a property that is not unique.

For example: 
Property `a` is the primary column (a unique UUID), `b` is the property I would like to sort by

```
  table
  --------
  a      b
  --------
  ag     1     
  sb     1
  sf     1
  xk     2
- bd     2
  ve     2
  ku     2
  lt     3
  ac     3
```

If I wanted to return the elements before and after a = `bd` sorted by `b`

Before

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b >= 2 ORDER BY b DESC, a DESC LIMIT x
```

After

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b <= 2 ORDER BY b ASC, a DESC OFFSET 1 LIMIT x
```

If the property of b was unique this would work. How would I do this on a non-unique property.

Comment: How big is this table? These queries will get very slow.

Comment: The table is very large but I have some additional where statements I can add to reduce it. With where conditions 10,000 - 50,000.

Comment: A union of forward-looking and backward-looking results might work better.

Comment: How would you do it sorted on a property thats not unqiue?

Comment: You probably have another column for secondary sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where a = 'bd') over (order by b, a rows between x preceding and x following) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7b5b1c815c8b23872a4ff3c4a9d1a6c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Running on 2million rows I got an execution time of ~2.3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation that does windowing

```
WITH
    data AS (SELECT * FROM id_value),
    before AS (
        SELECT * FROM id_value
            WHERE VALUE < (SELECT VALUE FROM id_value WHERE id = ID)
            ORDER BY VALUE DESC, id DESC
            limit 1200
    ),
    after AS (
        SELECT * FROM id_value
            WHERE VALUE >= (SELECT VALUE FROM id_value WHERE id = ID)
            ORDER BY VALUE ASC, id ASC
            limit 1200
    ),
    windowed AS (
        (SELECT * FROM before)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT * FROM after)
    )

SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
             COUNT(*) filter (
                 WHERE id = ID
             ) over (
                 ORDER BY VALUE, id rows BETWEEN 5 preceding AND 5 following
             ) AS cnt
    FROM windowed
) t
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `row_number()` as follows:

```
select a, b
from (
    select t.*, max(rn) filter(where a = 'bd') over() target_rn
    from (
        select t.*, row_number() over(order by b, a) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where abs(rn - target_rn) <= 2
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Before I put this as the accepted answer I would like to get the other methods working and do some benchmarks

Comment: Running this on [2 million rows](https://pastebin.com/C1BFkMcH) I got an execution time of ~3.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If the count of rows forward and backward is not a fixed number you might find something like this to be useful.

```
 with
    data as (select * from t /* or filter results here if complicated */),
    bck as (
        select *, dense_rank() over (order by b desc) grp
        from data where b < (select b from t where a = 'bd')
        -- where /* try filtering here first */
        order by b desc
        limit 100
    ),
    fwd as (
        select *, dense_rank() over (order by b) grp
        from data where b >= (select b from t where a = 'bd')
        -- where /* try filtering here first */
        order by b
        limit 100
    ) 
select * from bck where grp  = 1
union all
select * from fwd where grp <= 2
order by b;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a5318a7872bf5e7dc347a00ea4b9f3fc

Comment: Where am I supposed to specify the id property?

Comment: I can't get this working, could you put it into a db fiddle?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether you want a fixed number of rows or a fixed number of b-groups.